# Boolean function in Menu Program

Tags: c++, menu

OKAY! It all works. Now though, I have to add a boolean function in order to validate rather the grades entered in my users were valid... I have NO clue how to do this... Sigh. I don't even know where to begin, but I did set a prototype and start the function at the bottom... Do I have to include it in main? If so, where?

My professor seriously threw too much at us over spring break... Anyway, I have to create a boolean function that checks rather or not the values entered by the users range from 0-100, but I have no idea at all how to do this, with my program already being super complicated as it is... Anyway, here is the code, and the boolean function is at the bottom, I only declared the prototype, because I have no clue as to what my next step would be. Any help would be appreciated.

```
int menu();
void DisplayGrades (float, float, float, float, float, float); // In this function, it will display the grades the user enters. Used for choice 2.
float AssignmentGrade(float, float, float, float, float);
float LabTestGrade(float, float, float, float);                         // Prototypes to help me remember functions.
float LectureTestGrade(float, float, float, float, float);
float PostLabGrade(float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float);
float QuizGrade (float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float);
float ClickerGrade (float, float);
bool Gradeisvalid (float);
bool Choiceisvalid (int);





int main()
{
    float asgnment = 0, asgnment1 = 0, asgnment2 = 0, asgnment3 = 0,
        asgnment4 = 0, labtest = 0, labtest1 = 0, labtest2 = 0,
        labtest3 = 0, lecturetest = 0, lecturetest1 = 0, lecturetest2 = 0,   // Variables declared
        lecturetest3 = 0, lecturetest4 = 0, postlab = 0, p1 = 0, p2 = 0, p3 = 0, p4 = 0,
        p5 = 0, p6 = 0, p7 = 0, p8 = 0, p9 = 0, quiz = 0, quiz1 = 0, quiz2 = 0, quiz3 = 0, quiz4 = 0, quiz5 = 0,
        quiz6 = 0, quiz7 = 0, quiz8 = 0, quiz9 = 0, clicker = 0, clickergrade = 0, grade = 0;
    int choice;
    while(1)
    {
        choice = menu();
        if (choice ==4) break;
        switch (choice)

                    {
                                case 1:
                               asgnment=AssignmentGrade(asgnment, asgnment1, asgnment2, asgnment3, asgnment4);
                               labtest = LabTestGrade(labtest, labtest1, labtest2, labtest3);
                               lecturetest = LectureTestGrade(lecturetest, lecturetest1,  lecturetest2, lecturetest3, lecturetest4); // Typed this out to help remind of what I used
                               postlab = PostLabGrade(postlab, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9);
                               quiz = QuizGrade(quiz, quiz1, quiz2, quiz3, quiz4, quiz5, quiz6, quiz7, quiz8, quiz9);
                               clickergrade = ClickerGrade (clickergrade, clicker);
                                break;
                                case 2:
                                DisplayGrades (asgnment, labtest, lecturetest, postlab, quiz, clickergrade);
                                break;
                                case 3:
                                grade =  asgnment + labtest + lecturetest + postlab + quiz + clickergrade;
                                cout << "Your total grade is " << grade << "%" << endl;
                                if (grade <= 100 && grade >=90)
                                   cout << "Letter grade A" << endl << endl;
                                else if (grade <= 89 &&grade >= 80)
                                    cout << "Letter grade B" << endl << endl;
                                else if (grade <= 79 && grade >=70)
                                    cout << "Letter grade C" << endl << endl;
                                else if (grade <= 69 && grade >=60)
                                    cout << "Letter grade D, a little more!" << endl << endl;
                                else if (grade <= 59 && grade >=1)
                                    cout << "Grade of F, you can do better!" << endl << endl;
                                else if (grade ==0)
                                    cout << "Don't press 3 first!" << endl << endl;
    }

    }




return 0;
}

//Menu Options

int menu()
{
    int choice;
    cout << "Please select an option below." << endl << endl;
    cout << "1. Enter Grades" << endl;
    cout << "2. Display Grades" << endl;
    cout << "3. Show Overall Grade" << endl;
    cout << "4. Exit the Program"<< endl;
    cout << "Enter your choice... ";
    cin >> choice;
    return choice;
}

//AssignmentGrade Function

float AssignmentGrade(float asgnment, float asgnment1, float asgnment2, float asgnment3, float asgnment4)
{
    cout << "Okay, lets get started!" << endl;
    cout << "Please enter your first assignment grade " << endl;
    cin >> asgnment1;
    cout << endl << "Enter your second assignment grade " << endl;
    cin >> asgnment2;
    cout << endl << "Enter your final assignment grade " << endl;
    cin >> asgnment3;
    asgnment = asgnment1*0.05 + asgnment2*0.05 + asgnment3 *0.05;
    return asgnment;
}
// LabTestGrade Function

float LabTestGrade(float labtest, float labtest1, float labtest2, float labtest3)
{
  cout << "Now you are going to enter your 3 lab test grades. " <<endl;
  cout << "Please enter your first lab test score" <<endl;
  cin >> labtest1;
  cout << endl << "Now enter your second score" <<endl;
  cin >> labtest2;
  cout << endl << "Lastly, your final score" <<endl;
  cin >> labtest3;
  labtest = labtest1*0.10 + labtest2*0.10 + labtest3*0.10;
  return labtest;

}
// LectureTestGrade Function
float LectureTestGrade (float lecturetest, float lecturetest1, float lecturetest2, float lecturetest3, float lecturetest4)
{
  cout << "Next, you're going to enter your 4 Lecture Test grades." << endl;
  cout << "Please enter your first lecture test grade" << endl;
  cin >> lecturetest1;
  cout << endl << "Now enter your second grade" << endl;
  cin >> lecturetest2;
  cout << endl << "Next, your third score" << endl;
  cin >> lecturetest3;
  cout << endl << "Finally, your fourth score" << endl;
  cin >> lecturetest4;
  lecturetest = lecturetest1*0.10 + lecturetest2*0.10 + lecturetest3*0.10 + lecturetest4*0.10;
  return lecturetest;
}
// PostLabGrade Function
float PostLabGrade(float postlab, float p1, float p2, float p3, float p4, float p5, float p6, float p7, float p8, float p9)
{
  cout << "Now, enter your 9 Post Lab grades" << endl;
  cin >> p1 >> p2 >> p3 >> p4 >> p5 >> p6 >> p7 >> p8 >> p9;
  postlab = p1*0.003 + p2*0.003 + p3*0.003 + p4*0.003 + p5*0.003 + p6*0.003 + p7*0.003 + p8*0.003 + p9*0.003;
  return postlab;

}
// QuizGrade Function
float QuizGrade (float quiz, float quiz1, float quiz2, float quiz3, float quiz4, float quiz5, float quiz6, float quiz7, float quiz8, float quiz9)
{
  cout << "9 more grades to enter, this time, please enter your quiz grades" << endl;
  cin >> quiz1 >> quiz2 >> quiz3 >> quiz4 >> quiz5 >> quiz6 >> quiz7 >> quiz8 >> quiz9;
  quiz = quiz1*0.004 + quiz2*0.004 + quiz3*0.004 + quiz4*0.004 + quiz5*0.004 + quiz6*0.004 + quiz7*0.004 + quiz8*0.004 + quiz9*0.004;
  return quiz;
}
// ClickerGrade Function
float ClickerGrade (float clickergrade, float clicker)
{
  cout << "Almost done! Now, enter your total clicker grade." << endl;
  cin >> clicker;
  cout << "Finished! Next..." << endl;
  clickergrade = clicker*0.037;
  return clickergrade;
}
// DisplayGrade Function
void DisplayGrades (float asgnment, float labtest, float lecturetest, float postlab, float quiz, float clickergrade)
{
cout << "Grades" << endl << endl;
cout  << "Assignment";
cout << std::right << std::setw(7)<< asgnment << "%" << endl;
cout  << "Lab Test";
cout << std::right << std::setw(9)<< labtest << "%" << endl;
cout << "Lecture";
cout << std::right << std::setw(10)<< lecturetest << "%" << endl;
cout << "Post Lab";
cout << std::right << std::setw(9)<< postlab << "%" << endl;
cout << "Quiz";
cout << std::right << std::setw(13)<< quiz << "%" << endl;
cout <<"Clicker";
cout << std::right << std::setw(10)<< clickergrade << "%" << endl;
}
// Valid grade function
bool Gradeisvalid (float score)
{


}
```

Comment: *Did I mess up my menu function, wrong while placement?* - Yes, you did.

Comment: There's lots going on here and it's hard to tell exactly what you're after, but after looking at your functions my best guess is that you are passing your assignment variables by value when you want to pass them by reference, in which case you don't need to return a value.  Or you need to have something `var=AssignmentGrade(...);` to store the returned value into.

Comment: As @Tuffwer indicated,  `asgnment` the parameter to `AssignmentGrade`, is not the same variable as the one inside the method. Any changes you make to the automatic variable (the received parameter) in the method will be lost on return. You need either pass the **address** of each parameter to the method and use it to change the caller's copy, or find some other way of sharing multiple results. Else DisplayGrades will not have the results.

Comment: @BryanT, thats exactly my issue, but I'm such a noob at C++ that I have no clue how to do that ): This is our first time doing loops in conjunction with functions.

Comment: Usually a methods returns its result, but if you need to pass back several it's not that simple.
You can pass the address `my_func( &arg1, &arg2)` and in `my_func` say *arg1 = calculated_result`, etc.
Another way is to pass around a structure. And there are ugly ways with globals!
Maybe the root of your particular problem is that the IO (getting values from user) happens inside the same function that does the math?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't compile but this is critical:

- You didn't initialize your variables before sending them to functions
- You need to use `if (choice == 4)` instead of `while()`
- `int menu()` needs to `return` something

Here is your int `main()` as a FirstStep ;) `case 2` will only display initial values, zeros. And check my previous notes for the whole compilation then it will work.

```
int main()
{
    float asgnment = 0, asgnment1 = 0, asgnment2 = 0, asgnment3 = 0,
        asgnment4 = 0, labtest = 0, labtest1 = 0, labtest2 = 0,
        labtest3 = 0, lecturetest = 0, lecturetest1 = 0, lecturetest2 = 0,   
        lecturetest3 = 0, lecturetest4 = 0, postlab = 0, p1 = 0, p2 = 0, p3 = 0, p4 = 0,
        p5 = 0, p6 = 0, p7 = 0, p8 = 0, p9 = 0, quiz = 0, quiz1 = 0, quiz2 = 0, quiz3 = 0, quiz4 = 0, quiz5 = 0,
        quiz6 = 0, quiz7 = 0, quiz8 = 0, quiz9 = 0, clicker = 0, clickergrade = 0;

    int choice;
    choice = menu(); // let menu() return the entered int
    switch(choice)
    {
    case 1:
        AssignmentGrade(asgnment, asgnment1, asgnment2, asgnment3, asgnment4);
        LabTestGrade(labtest, labtest1, labtest2, labtest3);
        LectureTestGrade(lecturetest, lecturetest1, lecturetest2, lecturetest3, lecturetest4); 
        PostLabGrade(postlab, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9);
        QuizGrade(quiz, quiz1, quiz2, quiz3, quiz4, quiz5, quiz6, quiz7, quiz8, quiz9);
        ClickerGrade(clickergrade, clicker); break;

    case 2:
    DisplayGrades(asgnment, labtest, lecturetest, postlab, quiz, clickergrade);
    }

    return 0;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute it in a loop, like this:

```
int main()
{
    int choice;
    while(1)
    {
       choice = menu();
       if (choice == 4) break;
       your_code_with_switch_here;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

See when a user enters 4, the loop stops `if (choice == 4) break;`. Otherwise the loop continues.

Thanks to [@FirstStep](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35951298/3686755) your menu procedure didn't work well. It has to be rewritten like this (return the value):

```
int menu()
{
    int choice;
    cout << "Please select an option below." << endl << endl;
    cout << "1. Enter Grades" << endl;
    cout << "2. Display Grades" << endl;
    cout << "3. Show Overall Grade" << endl;
    cout << "4. Exit the Program"<< endl; // Will quit the program by using a while statement
    cout << "Enter your choice... ";
    cin >> choice;
    return choice;
}
```